# angle between vectors - only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, vector, angle

I have two 2D vectors v0L and v1L.

```
def magnitude(v1):
    return(np.sqrt(v1[0]**2 +v1[1]**2))

def angle(v1, v2):
    return acos(np.dot(v1, v2) / (magnitude(v1) * magnitude(v2)))

angle(v0L,v1L)
```

Why is this giving me a " only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" error?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Definition of `v0L, v1L` ?

Answer (score 0):

Change `acos` to `np.arccos`. You can get that error if `acos` refers to `math.acos`:

```
In [9]: math.acos(np.ones(2))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

In [11]: np.arccos(np.ones(2))
Out[11]: array([ 0.,  0.])
```

`math.acos` expects a scalar (or length-1 array) as input. `np.arccos` can accept a NumPy array (or a scalar).